# panda looping large size file how to get the amount of chunks?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, large-files

I'm using pandas to read a large size file,the file size is 11 GB

```
chunksize=100000
for df_ia in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=n,
                         iterator=True, low_memory=False):
```

My question is how to get the amount of the all the chunks,now what I can do is setting a index and count one by one,but this looks not a smart way:

```
index = 0
chunksize=100000
for df_ia in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=n,
                         iterator=True, low_memory=False):
    index + =1
```

So after looping the whole size file the final index will be the amount of all the chunks,but is there any faster way to direct get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `enumerate` function like:

```
for i, df_ia in enumerate(pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=5,
                                      iterator=True, low_memory=False)):
```

Then after you finish iteration, the value of `i` will be `len(number_of_dataframes)-1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
chunker = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=n,
                         iterator=True, low_memory=False)

chunker.chunksize # the number of chunks
```